# Siri voice to Text breaks AVPlayer video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer, siri

I have an app that is streaming Video data using an AVPlayer. The AVPlayer is using a APLEAGLView to render the pixels to the screen.

The issue I'm having is that I have a textbox within the same view. If you tap on the textbox and enter text with the keyboard it works fine.

However, if I use Siri's voice to text function on the textbox, then try play the video again, the audio plays and currentTime changes but the video is frozen on the frame that was there when you began the voice to text function.

This was fine previously but since a recent Apple update this is now broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as one of our biggest client's is complaining about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not find the exact cause of the issue, but I did manage to fix it.

The issue was that the previous developers used an OPEN GL ES View to render the pixel buffer to the screen. I refactored it to use the standard AVPlayerLayer functionality and that fixed the issue.